# how to change a char to the previous one of it (alphabetically) in string using c#?

Tags: c#, string, char, ascii

hello i am searching for a good approach to change a single char in a string to the previous char of it . i mean if i have this string = "abcd" i want to change the 'd' char to 'c' ? how to change the char to to the one before it (alphabetically) ?

i want to use the approach here:

```
int StringSize=0; 
string s=" ";
s = Console.ReadLine();
StringSize = s.Length;
s.Replace(s[StringSize-1],the previous char);
```

i want to change the char s [StringSize-1] to the previous char of it.

I've tried to do this depending on the ASCII code of the character but i did't find a method to convert form char to ASCII.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Re-assign it to `s`.

Comment: You cast the `char` to an `int` to get its numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is already ASCII, but to do math on it, you need a number.

So:

1. Cast to `int`
2. Do your math (subtract 1)
3. Cast back to `char`

   ```
   char newChar = (char)((int)oldChar - 1);
   ```

Or in your code:

```
s = s.Replace(s[StringSize-1], (char)((int)s[StringSize-1] - 1));
```

Caveats:

- This won't work with 'a' or 'A'
- Strings are **immutable** you can't just change a character. You can create a *new* string with the replaced character, but that isn't technically the same thing.

Comment: Technically, strings are immutable, however, you could probably create an `unsafe` function that manipulates the string using pointers. However, this is definitely NOT a good idea.

Comment: @icemanind Yes, you can do a lot more when you let pointers back in. As you say *not* a good idea, especially for someone new.

Answer (score 0):

Replace return string to object, but not change values on it. The solution's:

```
s = s.Replace(s[StringSize-1], the previous char);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = "abcd";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        str = str.Replace(str[i], (char)((byte)str[i] - 1));
    }
```